# How to tell if a machine on the network is running windows from a batch file

Tags: networking, ip, batch-file

Is it possible to tell if a given IP address (for a LAN network) is from a windows machine in a batch file? The device is not showing up in net view, but is responding to a direct ping.

Comment: `ping` uses ICMP protocol, which tells nothing about what OS the machine is running. You would need to add a service to discover this, or else make each machine on your network log its OS details on a shared network drive when it boots.

Comment: the answer that is marked might help. If you query the OS like this, you can tell it what do do based on what is returned for the OS value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101076/powershell-determine-the-remote-computer-os

Comment: You want to use a batch file to get detailed information about the computer that owns this IP via the given the IP, such as the MAC address, network configuration.Or you only want the operating system information.

Comment: Just the operating system.